# Jquery Ajax Protection

Tags: jquery, ajax, referrer

I want to know if there is a way to limit my ajax results to just my domain? In order to prevent a person from just creating a script and calling the ajax url.

Most people have informed me that referrer should not be trusted.

Comment: The answers here may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347881/how-to-prevent-cross-domain-ajax-requests

Comment: I would also agree with the poster who said that unless your page requires a login, there's no foolproof way to prevent its contents from being retrieved via AJAX.