# Ensure PHP page can only be called via AJAX from my page

Tags: php, ajax

I have a utilitypage.php that writes some database info. I call this PHP page via AJAX from mysite.com/mypage.html.

If some malicious visitor looks at the source code and finds the name of the php page being called, they can then go to that page directly or call it from some other site.

How can I ensure that utilitypage.php can only be called from mysite.com/mypage.html? (detect if it's called from elsewhere)

I looked at some $_SERVER variables but see they are not always reliable. The visitors to mypage.html are not authenticated users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A really simple (but possibly unreliable) way is to check the headers:

```
$isAjax = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest';
```

but they can be spoofed, so don't rely solely on them.

But as is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347881/how-to-prevent-cross-domain-ajax-requests) by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/610573/chris)

> There isn't any absolutely foolproof method to prevent this, since any
>   header information     can be spoofed. Session-based tokens are
>   another possible solution, but in that case your javascript is
>   publicly accessible, so anyone who wanted to spend a little time could
>   determine how your token system works and figure out a way around it.

The *only* way to make sure is to give each user a unique token and store it in their session. Then, just pass this token back when you make an ajax request and ensure it matches so you know the request is legit.

Check this out for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: CSRF tokens are the *only* way, not the *best* way.

Comment: Does storing the token in the user's Session require that utilitypage.php and mypage.html be on the same domain? If so, what if they can't be?

Comment: Yes it does, because PHP sessions are only stored within domains by default. If you want to do otherwise, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806701/secure-and-flexible-cross-domain-sessions). Besides, your mypage.html will have to be a PHP page or at least call another PHP page with an ajax call. This is because you need to generate the token on your `mypage`, so you can check it subsequently on your `utilitypage`.