# jquery ui tabs ajax load

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I would like to create a site "A" containing a jQueryUI-Tabset that calls the sites "B,C,D" via Ajax. BUT when someone finds site "B" on Google and calls it - is there a way to force that site "B" isn't displayed independently, but that it is always displayed in the tabset of site "A"?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to allow to display tabs by an URL. Quick example from jQuery tools can be found [here](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/history.html), you may also find [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813601/jquery-ui-tabs-back-button-history) interesting.

Then on the "B,C,D" pages you must somehow find out if the page is loaded as a tab or as a page. As you have AJAX here, the easiest way will be to check if the page is loaded [with AJAX request or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929432/how-server-can-check-ajax-requests-not-from-site-x-requested-with). Then - if not -  redirect to the tabbed page and specify the current tab, e.g. /pageA#tabB.