# How can i check if page accessed directly?

Tags: php

Hi :)
I want to forbid access of a page directly, what i mean is if some one try to access for example the page

> proccess.php

He will get an error message.
BUT! if the page is accessed via AJAX call, it will act normal.

i've tried:

```
if( preg_match( '/' . basename( __FILE__ ) . '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) )
{
 die("Error!");
}
```

but the problem is that when i access it via AJAX call, it act like i've accessed it directly...

please help :)

Comment: You could check the `x-requested-with` header information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check the [`HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`](http://steveluscher.com/archives/ajax-requests-x-requested-with-headers-and-unexpected-cache-contents) header.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
  // ajax request
} else {
  die('direct access is forbidden');
}
```

also read [Can the “x-requested-with” http header be spoofed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/623299/112968) on stackoverflow

Comment: i guess so … i think the header is implemented in the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
     die("Error!");
 }
```

Would maybe be sufficient?

Comment: i want to forbid direct access via URL, but if i am calling the page via AJAX it will work normal...

Comment: You cannot entierly forbid this. Both are from clients and one might spoof into the other. This is just a dumb check, but it's working as you like.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to set a variable to something (either true, false, a string...anything really) in all of the scripts that call this script *before* it calls process.php. Then the top line in process.php should be"

```
if ($checkVar === NULL) {

    die("Permission denied!");

}
```

But that would require you to edit all the pages that call the process page.